# Splitting a list into a rows in DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to convert a dataframe from

[image]

to

[image]

Column data is same in both Dataframes
Tags have to be split into multiple rows with the same data

Note that the dataset is quite big and I know the lame way to do this using loops.
I want a faster way to implement this for close to 100,000 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pandas dataframe, if your dataframe above is named **df**

```
pd.concat([Series(row["content"], row["titles"], row["data"],
           row["tags"].split(' ')) for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

then rename the columns appropriately.

---

But, if you start with a dictionary like,

```
 data = dict(titles = list("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"),
             content = list("aaa","bbb", "ccc"),
             tags = list("hhh ggg iii"))
```

you could do this before rendering a dataframe object,

```
 data.update({"tags": data["tags"].split(" ")})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if need something really fast, need `numpy` for vectorized solutions.

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeat values by legths by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flat values of nested `lists` by `chain`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                   'title':['title 1','title 2','title 3'],
                   'content':['content 1','content 1','content 1'],
                   'tags':['baking cookies texture',
                           'baking1 cookies1 texture1',
                            'baking2 cookies2 texture2'],
                   'data':['data 1','data 2','data 3']})

print (df)
     content    data  id                       tags    title
0  content 1  data 1   1     baking cookies texture  title 1
1  content 1  data 2   2  baking1 cookies1 texture1  title 2
2  content 1  data 3   3  baking2 cookies2 texture2  title 3
```

```
from  itertools import chain

#convert column tags to list by space
df.tags = df.tags.str.split()
#concanecate columns to one
df.data = df.title + df.content + df.data

#reshape 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "data": np.repeat(df.data.values, df.tags.str.len()),
        "tags": list(chain.from_iterable(df.tags))})

print (df1)
                     data      tags
0  title 1content 1data 1    baking
1  title 1content 1data 1   cookies
2  title 1content 1data 1   texture
3  title 2content 1data 2   baking1
4  title 2content 1data 2  cookies1
5  title 2content 1data 2  texture1
6  title 3content 1data 3   baking2
7  title 3content 1data 3  cookies2
8  title 3content 1data 3  texture2
```